# onChange access funtion not working in react js

Tags: reactjs

I have this toggle react component. I am trying to access  `handleChangeTogle` when i click on the  Toggle but call is not reaching `handleChangeTogle`.

What am i doing wrong here?

```
const handleChangeTogle = () => {
  setdomestic_voilence(!domestic_voilence);
};
```

```
<Toggle
  checked={domestic_voilence}
  text="Is Active"
  onChange={() => handleChangeTogle}
  offstyle="btn-danger"
  onstyle="btn-success"
/>
```

```
import React from "react";

function Toggle(props) {
  console.log(props);
  const {
    text,
    size = "default",
    defaultChecked,
    disabled,
    onChange,
    offstyle = "btn-danger",
    onstyle = "btn-success",
  } = props;

  let displayStyle = defaultChecked ? onstyle : offstyle;
  return (
    <>
      <label>
        <span className={` switch-wrapper`}>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            // checked={defaultChecked}

            // onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
          />
          <span className={`${displayStyle} switch`}>
            <span className="switch-handle" />
          </span>
        </span>
        {/* <span className="switch-label">gyyghiyg</span> */}
      </label>
    </>
  );
}

export default Toggle;
```

Comment: try passing only the name without an arrow function-
```onChange={handleChangeTogle}```

Comment: You are not calling the function, you miss parentheses. `onChange={() => handleChangeTogle()}`.

Comment: i tryed both ways i  have a consolelog inside   `const handleChangeTogle = () => { ` with some random text  but its not consolelogiing

Comment: can you share code for toggle component?

Comment: @MuhammadBilalBangash i have shred

Comment: @jisaks in above toggle component you commented out onChange

Comment: change you onChange call to ```onChange={handleChangeTogle}``` or ```onChange={(e) => handleChangeTogle(e)}``` and uncomment code for ```onChange``` in ```Toggle Component``` @jisaks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your problem and solved it this way. (I used typescript with React. You can remove Interface and types).

Toggle.tsx

```
   import React from "react";
   import { ToggleInterface } from './interfaces';

   const Toggle = ({ text, handleChange, offstyle, onstyle }: ToggleInterface) => {
    return (
     <>
        <label>
            <span className={`switch-wrapper`}>
                <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)} />
                <span className="switch">
                    <span className="switch-handle" />
                </span>
            </span>
         </label>
      </>
     );
   }

export default Toggle;
```

App.tsx

```
    const handleChangeToggle = () => {
       console.log("handleChangeToggle is worked !!");
    };

 return (
     <div className="App">
  
      <Toggle
        text="Is Active"
        handleChange={() => handleChangeToggle() }
        offstyle= "btn-danger"
        onstyle= "btn-success"
       />
   );

 }
 export default App;
```

interface.ts

```
    export interface ToggleInterface {
        text: string,
        handleChange: Function,
        offstyle: string,
        onstyle: string
    }
```